# How to dynamically bind select box with parent child relationship

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically bind select box with parent child relationship, I've below object in javascript:

```
var jsonData = [{
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Program Type",
            "field_value": "Select program type",
            "type_id": "1",
            "width": "500",
            "height": "500",
            "children": [{
                "id": "2",
                "title": "Type A",
                "field_value": "Type A",
                "type_id": "1",
                "width": "500",
                "height": "500",
                "children": [{
                    "id": "4",
                    "title": "No of Days",
                    "field_value": "No of Days",
                    "type_id": "1",
                    "width": "500",
                    "height": "500",
                    "children": [{
                        "id": "6",
                        "title": "3 Days",
                        "field_value": "3 Days",
                        "type_id": "1",
                        "width": "500",
                        "height": "500",
                        "children": []
                    }, {
                        "id": "7",
                        "title": "2 Days",
                        "field_value": "2 Days",
                        "type_id": "1",
                        "width": "500",
                        "height": "500",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }, {
                    "id": "5",
                    "title": "color of the car",
                    "field_value": "color of the car",
                    "type_id": "1",
                    "width": "500",
                    "height": "500",
                    "children": [{
                        "id": "8",
                        "title": "Red",
                        "field_value": "Red",
                        "type_id": "1",
                        "width": "500",
                        "height": "500",
                        "children": []
                    }, {
                        "id": "9",
                        "title": "Black",
                        "field_value": "Black",
                        "type_id": "1",
                        "width": "500",
                        "height": "500",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                "id": "3",
                "title": "Type B",
                "field_value": "Type B",
                "type_id": "1",
                "width": "500",
                "height": "500",
                "children": [{
                    "id": "10",
                    "title": "typ b child a",
                    "field_value": "typ b child a",
                    "type_id": "1",
                    "width": "500",
                    "height": "500",
                    "children": []
                }, {
                    "id": "11",
                    "title": "typ b child b",
                    "field_value": "typ b child b",
                    "type_id": "1",
                    "width": "500",
                    "height": "500",
                    "children": []
                }]
            }]
        }];
```

Based on the above object on page load I'm trying to generate below output:

Program Type : (select box with option Type A and Type B) and when user select Type A it will generate another select box with it's children which is (No of Days and color of the car) and so on, At the end I've a html button which will be deactivated once all child select boxes displayed on form then button should be activated.

I tried many way but didn't succeed e.g.

```
var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($allData); ?>;
jsonData.forEach(function (rootObject) {

displayObj += '<div class="row">';
displayObj += '<div class="col-md-6">';
displayObj += '<label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label"> '+rootObject.title+' </label>';
displayObj += '<select id="'+rootObject.title.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')+'" class="form-select" onchange="handleSelectChange(this)">>';

displayObj += '<option value="0"> '+rootObject.field_value+' </option>';

    rootObject.children.forEach(function (childObj){

        displayObj += '<option value="'+childObj.field_value+'"> '+childObj.field_value+' </option>';
    });

displayObj += '</select>';
displayObj += '</div>';
displayObj += '</div>';
```

});

```
$('#select-container').html(displayObj);
function renderOptions(options, parentId) {
var select = $('<select>', {
    id: parentId,
    class: 'form-select',
    onchange: 'handleSelectChange(this)'
});

select.append('<option value="">Select an option</option>');

options.forEach(function (option) {
    select.append('<option value="' + option.id + '"> ' + option.title + '</option>');
});
$('#select-container').append(select);
```

}

```
function handleSelectChange(select) {
var selectedValue = $(select).val();
console.log('Selected value:', selectedValue);

// Remove existing child select boxes
$(select).nextAll('select').remove();

// Check if the selected option has children
var selectedOption = jsonData.find(obj => obj.id == selectedValue);
if (selectedOption && selectedOption.children && selectedOption.children.length > 0) {
    // Create and append a new select box for each child
    renderOptions(selectedOption.children, selectedOption.title.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_'));
}
```

}

Thank you in advance for your help Guys.

Best Regards,
R

Comment: Tutorial video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=QFW2o1GA60k

Answer (score 0):

i hope this can help you... it's is far to be perfect but clarify some concept:

```
//here  you should pass childObj.id and not childObj.field_value in option value
displayObj += '<option value="'+childObj.field_value+'"> '+childObj.field_value+' </option>';

//this will not remove anithing becouse $(select).nextAll('select') is always empty
$(select).nextAll('select').remove();
//and this is the hardest to understand....
//selectedOption is always undefined because Array.find() is not recursive
// you are searching only on first layer of the array (only obj.id == 1 will be true) 
var selectedOption = jsonData.find(obj => obj.id == selectedValue);

//so you need to create your own recursive search like  function findValues(){...}

//i hope this is usefull to you in some way , have a nice day.
```

```js
var jsonData = [{
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Program Type",
            "field_value": "Select program type",
            "type_id": "1",
            "width": "500",
            "height": "500",
            "children": [{
                "id": "2",
                "title": "Type A",
                "field_value": "Type A",
                "type_id": "1",
                "width": "500",
                "height": "500",
                "children": [{
                    "id": "4",
                    "title": "No of Days",
                    "field_value": "No of Days",
                    "type_id": "1",
                    "width": "500",
                    "height": "500",
                    "children": [{
                        "id": "6",
                        "title": "3 Days",
                        "field_value": "3 Days",
                        "type_id": "1",
                        "width": "500",
                        "height": "500",
                        "children": []
                    }, {
                        "id": "7",
                        "title": "2 Days",
                        "field_value": "2 Days",
                        "type_id": "1",
                        "width": "500",
                        "height": "500",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }, {
                    "id": "5",
                    "title": "color of the car",
                    "field_value": "color of the car",
                    "type_id": "1",
                    "width": "500",
                    "height": "500",
                    "children": [{
                        "id": "8",
                        "title": "Red",
                        "field_value": "Red",
                        "type_id": "1",
                        "width": "500",
                        "height": "500",
                        "children": []
                    }, {
                        "id": "9",
                        "title": "Black",
                        "field_value": "Black",
                        "type_id": "1",
                        "width": "500",
                        "height": "500",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                "id": "3",
                "title": "Type B",
                "field_value": "Type B",
                "type_id": "1",
                "width": "500",
                "height": "500",
                "children": [{
                    "id": "10",
                    "title": "typ b child a",
                    "field_value": "typ b child a",
                    "type_id": "1",
                    "width": "500",
                    "height": "500",
                    "children": []
                }, {
                    "id": "11",
                    "title": "typ b child b",
                    "field_value": "typ b child b",
                    "type_id": "1",
                    "width": "500",
                    "height": "500",
                    "children": []
                }]
            }]
        }];
       
window.displayObj="";
jsonData.forEach(function (rootObject) {
  displayObj += '<div class="row">';
  displayObj += '<div class="col-md-6">';
  displayObj += '<label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label"> '+rootObject.title+' </label>';
  displayObj += '<select id="'+rootObject.title.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')+'" class="form-select" onchange="handleSelectChange(this)">>';

  displayObj += '<option value="0"> '+rootObject.field_value+' </option>';

  rootObject.children.forEach(function (childObj){

      displayObj += '<option value="'+childObj.id+'"> '+childObj.field_value+' </option>';
  });

  displayObj += '</select>';
  displayObj += '</div>';
  displayObj += '</div>';
});

$('#select-container').html(displayObj);
function renderOptions(options, parentId) {
  var select = $('<select>', {
      id: parentId,
      class: 'form-select removable',
      onchange: 'handleSelectChange(this)'
  });

  select.append('<option value="">Select an option</option>');

  options.forEach(function (option) {
      select.append('<option value="' + option.id + '"> ' + option.title + '</option>');
  });
  $('#select-container').append(select);
}

function handleSelectChange(select) {
  var selectedValue = $(select).val();
  console.log('Selected value:', selectedValue);

  // Remove existing child select boxes


  // Check if the selected option has children
  var selectedOption = findValue(jsonData,selectedValue);
  if (selectedOption && selectedOption.children && selectedOption.children.length > 0) {
      $('select.removable').remove();
      // Create and append a new select box for each child
      renderOptions(selectedOption.children, selectedOption.title.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_'));
  }
}


function findValue(arr, val){
    for(var i =0;i <arr.length;i++){
      obj=arr[i];
      if(obj.id==val){
        return obj;
      }else if("children" in obj){
        let result = findValue(obj.children, val);
        if (result) {
            return result;
        }
      }
    }
    return undefined;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-container"></div>
```